# Three.js: animated gltf model looks disconnected in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, blender, gltf

I made a gltf file with bone animation by using Blender.

It works well in Blender but not in Three.js
The model looks disconnected when they are moving.
[Comparing my model in blender(upper pics) and in three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvFxO.jpg)

I tried several ways to solve it but did not make it.

Can you give me a solution to this?

Comment: Please always share your Blender file and model data with all assets (e.g. textures) when asking such questions. Beside, please link the used `glTF` Exporter.

Comment: 1. Did you use the built-in blender exporter, or any other converter? 2. Does the model look right in other viewers (e.g. any other one from https://github.com/cx20/gltf-test , like BablylonJS?)